# I realized TradingView is opening the long one candle later. How to fixed it?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

With the following code the short position is created one candle after when the condition is met.
But I need the position opened when the current cross the RSI.

How to change this? this is the code:

```
//@version=5
strategy("RSI Strategy", overlay=true)
length = input( 14 )
overSold = input( 30 )
overBought = input( 70 )
price = close
vrsi = ta.rsi(price, length)
co = ta.crossover(vrsi, overSold)
cu = ta.crossunder(vrsi, overBought)
if (not na(vrsi))
    if (co)
        strategy.entry("RsiLE", strategy.long, comment="RsiLE")
    if (cu)
        strategy.entry("RsiSE", strategy.short, comment="RsiSE")
//plot(strategy.equity, title="equity", color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_areabr)
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHNyw.png)

I was waiting TV opening the trade at the correct candle but is being opened one candle after.

Answer (score 0):

Pinescript is opening the short from values from the good candle.

But on the screen, it is drawn at the beginning of the next candle (the top of your bearish candle).

As you can see, the value is also the value of the close of you precedent candle, on which the calculation where made.

Pinescript does like this :
At the close of the candle, it can calculate your strategy and decide to short or not. If the Short is decided, it will drawn the short symbol at the opening of the next candle (which is also the close of the precedent candle)

[Edit]
in pinescript, the script is executed in loop each time a new bar is calculated.
You can force your script to be executed on each tick with :

```
calc_on_every_tick=true
```

in your strategy declaration (see : https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy)

Perhaps it will help you to overcome the on bar one script execution limitation.

Comment: I got what you explained.
I need to open an order immediately when the current bar pass the high of the previous bar in the 2min chart under some conditions(but I will not explain these other conditions for simplicity purposes)
I think maybe this can be done with this  (notice I am using 1 second with request.security):

longCondition =open[1]==request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1s", close)
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Buy",strategy.long)
strategy.close("Buy")

But this is not working.

Note: I am using only longCondition in the "if" function just for simplicity purposes.

Comment: @DoeJ I update my answer. Using request.security won't solve your problem as it will be executed once on each new bar on your chart (every 2 min)

Comment: Hello. I tried calc_on_every_tick=true yesterday and did not work. So is it impossible  open a buy order immediately when the current candle pass the previous candle high?

Comment: another idea: what if I replace for my entire strategy close[1] with
request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1", close[1]) and so on to use always 1min timeframe for the entire strategy.
Then use my strategy only with the 1 second chart, so this will open "almost immediately" the buy order when a 1 second  bar close above the previous close from the 1minute chart, right?